# external site with my header

Tags: jquery, css

I need a page with my header and an external site below. I need the user to be able to navigate the external site below while my header persists. I don't need to show the URL of that external page.

When the page loads initially I want it to look like one solid page with a text input field, where a URL can be loaded. When the form is submitted I'd like my header to slide up to preset width of say, a height of 100px and load the URL into the are below.

Do I need to use frames, iframe or something else?

I guess I'll use jQuery to resize the header on click?..

Just trying to understand the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could use iframes if you are wanting to display another site on your own website.

Or you could use AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to load an external website onto your website.

IFrames would be the easiest to implement.